# Something like a return value of an action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I'm wondering if there is a best practice to simulate something like a return value for an ngrx Action.

Let's say, I've got a common component for creating a new address. This can be called from multiple places all over the application:

```
@Effect()
createAddress: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(mod.CREATE_NEW_ADDRESS)
    .map(() => go("/address/create"));
```

When the user then types in all address infos and saves the address, the caller -
 and only the caller - should get notified about this and update himself (for example, add the address to a combobox or display it textually in a summary).

Thus, a single field "latestCreatedAddress" in the Store would not be sufficient. I would need multiple fields, each one for each caller.

Is there some smart way to handle cases like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give specific advice without seeing what your current AppState looks like.  You'll just need to have various parts of the AppState contain the addresses as needed.

For example for stack overflow we can add comments right under your question and right under my answer.  The AppState (for simplicity not normalizing the data) would look something like this:

```
{
  question: [{
    text: 'some question',
    comments: ['a', 'b'],
    answers: [{
        text: 'some answer',
        comments: ['c']
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comments here would be similar to your address which is a child of some other piece of data.